# Nuxt 3 console.log isn't working for ssr, why?

Tags: nuxt.js, cross-browser, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm currently migrating my app from nuxt 2 to nuxt 3... now I can't debug things as console.log on browser console not showing.

Please suggest what setting to set for SSR. Eslint config I've added rules

```js
'no-console': 'off',
```

Here you can see my component

```js
export default {

  setup(){
    const articleStore = useArticleStore();
    console.log('setup log init')
    articleStore.loadLatest();
    articleStore.loadPopular();
    articleStore.loadRecommended();
    return {articleStore};
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selectedTab: 'latest',
      selectedArticles: []
    }
  },

  computed: {
    latest() {
      return this.articleStore.latest;
    },
    popular() {
      return this.articleStore.popular;
    },
    recommended() {
      return this.articleStore.recommended;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    changeArticleTab(name) {
      console.log('hello')
      this.selectedTab = name;
      this.selectedArticles = this.latest;//this[name].slice(0, 3);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log('testing testin ')
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.changeArticleTab('latest');
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

[here is my console snap... click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgTfb.png)

Comment: Did you checked your bash console (server-side, not in the browser). Also, please provide more context as of where you do call that `console.log` please.

Comment: I've call `console.log` inside mounted and methods...

`pinia` store console display on bash console but not on browser console.

Comment: neither I can see my backend api-calls in my network network tab...

Comment: If you do that server side, seems legit. Depends how the backend calls are made. Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: Please edit your question, not in comments since it's unreadable as you can see.

Comment: @kissu I've added more info.. please review, if you need anything else. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Which `console.log` is not showing? It's probably because of `setTimeout` anyway, there is a specific way that the event loop works.

Comment: all console.log not showing... not anywhere in the app.

Comment: What are you store functions doing? Are you sure they are working? Don't they need to be awaited? What about commenting them and getting something to work? Let's focus on that one first.